# RabbitMQ RPC producer with Multithreading

Tags: java, rabbitmq

How can i implement a RPC call in multithread environnement?
In the basic tutorial here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html , in multithread environnement, I see two problems:

-If all is in different thread (including constructor), we create a reply queue for each thread, i don't thing it is a good idea (no ?)

-If only fibonacciRpc.call("4") is in different thread, the consumer for the reply queue can consume the bad reply, and the original consumer for this reply will wait indefinitely.

I did not found any solution for now but maybe a I did not understand something.

Comment: In the example every thread should have an independent, transient reply queue. Why do you think that would be a problem?

Comment: My application is a web application, with possibly a lot of request at same time, so, a lot of creation and deletion of reply queue.

The thing i don't understand in example is "Correlation id", because we create a queue for each RPC request so, the check of "correlation id" is 
unnecessary, the message in reply queue is inevitably for the request. And if queue are for several request, we are in my second second

Maybe my mistake is my bad english...

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert on RabbitMQ, but my understanding is that the reply queue is transient, in other words, it needs not to be persistent, which means it is just a memory queue, and therefore should be quite fast to create. Also, the reply queue is per consumer, not per request, which means every thread corresponds with a consumer, if your thread/consumer makes multiple requests then all can travel through the same reply queue, in whose case the correlation ID is necessary to determine which request owns the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case :
channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, **new DefaultConsumer(channel) {}** is causing alot of heap size in memory and it does not gets cleared as long as i do not delete channel.

As per Internet , you are supposed to create one connection.
create channel per thread and create separate queue per channel and delete queue after you read the response , if you do not it will keep creating new queue over and over, in the same channel.

But new DefaultConsumer is creating alot of heap memory.

Looks like to get rid of this I have to delete channel.